# how to get a particular index of array using smarty templates

Tags: php, smarty

hi I am developing a module in [oxid-esales](http://www.oxid-esales.com/). It use smarty templates. Now I want to get a particular array index. My code looks like

```
[{foreach from=$language item=lang}]
  <div id="stores">
   [{if !array_key_exists($lang->id,$language_array)}]
     <img src="[{$join_image}]" /> <input type="radio" name="sys_lang" id="sys_lang" />[{$lang->name}]
   [{else}]
    <img src="[{$join_image}]" /> [{$lang->name}] [{$language_array[$lang->id]}]
[{/if}]
 </div>
[{/foreach}]
```

But it is creating a fatal error of

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in froomerce_fconnect.tpl line 74]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $language_array[$lang->id] (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in D:\wamp\www\oxid_froomerce\core\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1093
```

I have searched and all where the proper syntax for getting variables in smary is only putting`{}` brackets. But the CMS oxid enforces me to use `[{}]` for variables.
Does any body how can I get the value of particular index of array like this

```
[{$language_array[$lang->id]}]
```

Regards,
Awais Qarni

Comment: I dont know such CMS, but when you say "CMS oxid enforces me to use `[{}]` for variables", what exactly you mean?

Smarty uses own syntax and parse templates accordingly their own rules: substitude variables in placeholders and call methods of assigned objects.

So, when you use `[{}]` in your code - what do you expect? Are you sure, that you need to use  them?

Comment: @v2p thanks for your response.. I mean if we want to echo or use a php variable sent by our class we use `{}` to outside the variable. But in oxid I have to wrap`{}` with `[]`. This is the reason I am getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change default smarty delimiters.
For example:

```
$smarty->left_delimiter = '[{';
$smarty->right_delimiter = '}]';
```

See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.escaping.tpl